# For Loop in MySQL, looping through a table and applying it to a where statement

Tags: mysql, loops, for-loop, join

My problem is how to loop through a table and extract information from another table.

I have a table - X with 470 records:

```
A      B     C
111    12    18
121    21    29
127    37    101
```

I would like to write the following query:

```
create or replace view NEW as 
For j = 1-3     
Select * from Y
  where imei = X.A(j) and id > X.B(j) and id < X.C(j)
```

Apologies, I am a matlab programmer so I have used that syntax above to explain what I want. How can I do this in MySql? I have looked up For Loops but mostly it loops through within the same table. I need to loop through a different table and use those criteria in the where statement of a different table.

Comment: There are no loops in SQL.

Comment: What is `X.A(j)` supposed to mean? Do you mean the value of `A` in the `j`th row of table `X`? MySQL tables don't have row numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To get 3 rows from a table, use `LIMIT 3` in a subquery. To get related rows in another table, use `JOIN`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW new AS
SELECT Y.*
FROM Y
JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM X
      LIMIT 3) AS X ON Y.ime1 = X.a AND Y.id > X.b AND Y.id < X.c
```

To make `LIMIT 3` produce predictable results, you should have an `ORDER BY` clause in the subquery. Otherwise, it will select an arbitrary set of 3 rows from `X`.